# From Stata to R: creating a scatterplot with vertical date lines on a subset

Tags: r, ggplot2, stata, graphing, subset

## Introduction

I am trying to replicate in R a time-series scatterplot I have created in Stata on a subset of data. The scatterplot has the time variable 'date' on the x-axis (mm/dd/yyyy) and the integer variable 'cost' on the y-axis (monetary amount, in USD). The marker labels are of a categorical variable, 'company name'.

The actual dataset is very large, but a sample would look like the following (see R code below), with observations (i.e. rows) indicating transactions (column 1), followed by variables indicating the date of the transaction (column 2), the cost of the transaction (column 3), and the name of the company that initiated the transaction (column 4).

```
#Sample Data Frame (R Code)

transactionID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4) 
date <- as.Date(c("2006-08-06", "2008-07-30", "2009-04-16", "2013-02-05"))
cost <- as.integer(c(1208, 23820, 402, 89943))
company <- c("ACo", "BInc", "CInd", "DOp")
thedata <- data.frame(transactionID, date, cost, company)
```

## Doing it in Stata

The scatterplot I want will  have 'date' on the x-axis and 'cost' on the y-axis, 'company' listed as the marker labels, and will also have 3 vertical lines of various formatting to signify important events. The steps to producing this in Stata are

1. Identify x-axis points for vertical lines at the dates September 10 2007, January 28 2008, January 18 2012, and February 5 2013.

> display mdy(9,10,2007)
>
> display mdy(1, 28, 2008)
>
> display mdy(2, 5, 2013)

The three display commands above return the values 17419, 17559, 19394, which are how Stata reads those days internally, and which are embedded in the code below for graphing the scatterplot.

2. Create the scatterplot, adding in the three vertical lines from Step 1, formatting them as as dotted, dashed, and solid lines of red, blue, and green colors and of different thicknesses, with 'cost' on the y-axis, 'date' on the x-axis, and 'company' name as the marker labels, for only those transactions that were less than or equal to $3,000:

> graph twoway scatter cost date if cost <= 3000 , mlabel(company) xline(17419, lpatt(dot) lwidth(thick) lcol(red)) xline(17559, lpatt(dash) lwidth(medthick) lcol(blue)) xline(19394, lpatt(solid) lwidth(thin) lcol(green))

## Problems Doing it in R

When I've tried to replicate it in R I have encountered the following problems

1. cannot figure out how to add vertical lines at those specific dates, nor how to change the size formatting of them
2. Y-axis ('cost') are in scientific notation (i.e. 2e+05) instead of regular numbers (i.e. 200,000)
3. I don't quite understand subsetting in R; in Stata I can easily add "if" qualifiers to examine specific data subsets (e.g. "if cost > 3000 & transactionID < 5") and then easily modify them to re-run the analyses or plot the graphs on other various subsets. But in R it seems that there are extra steps involved where you have to subset the data first and store it as a new object and then run the analysis on that object. Is that right? I see some benefits to this, but also some demerits (such as having hundreds of different objects cluttering up your work environment as you explore the data, for instance).

So far I have pieced together the following code. I originally tried to do it with the base R installation commands plot() and text(), but it seems like it cannot be done in base R. So then I tried using the ggplot2 package but still can't quite figure it out like I could in Stata:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(thedata, aes(date, cost)) + 
       geom_text( label = thedata$company, color="blue", vjust = 0) +  
       geom_vline( xintercept = as.numeric( thedata$date[
                      c(I don't know what goes here, or here)]), 
                  linetype="dotted", color="red")
```

As you can see, I cannot figure out how the coordinates for the xintercept of the geom_vline command work (and can't find it in the official help file), specifically when I want them to be dates (particularly dates that may or not be in the data frame), nor can I figure out how to change the thickness of the line.

Comment: This question is too long. Anyway, a picture of your stata graph would be helpful. And you are mistaken in the believe that you have to store subsets as new objects. You can easily do something like `someFunction(yourData[subsettingCondition,])`.

Comment: In Stata, you can evaluate the dates inline: you can have ``xline(`=mdy(9,10,2007)', lpatt(dot) lwidth(thick) lcol(red))``, etc., embedded in the `graph` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very nicely done question. If you are still interested in a base solution:

```
transactionID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
date <- as.Date(c("2006-08-06", "2008-07-30", "2009-04-16", "2013-02-05"))
cost <- as.integer(c(1208, 23820, 402, 89943))
company <- c("ACo", "BInc", "CInd", "DOp")
thedata <- data.frame(transactionID, date, cost, company)


par(mar = c(5,7,3,2), tcl = .2, las = 1)
with(thedata, 
     plot(date, cost, xlab = 'Date', ylab = '', axes = FALSE, main = 'a plot'))
dseq <- seq.Date(as.Date('2006-01-01'), as.Date('2013-01-01'), by = 'year')
axis.Date(1, at = dseq, labels = format(dseq, format = '%Y'))
# axis.Date(1, at = seq.Date(min(date), max(date), by = 'year'))
axis(2, at = pretty(cost), 
     labels = format(pretty(cost), scientific = FALSE, big.mark = ','))
## add lines at specified dates
abline(v = as.Date(c('2007-09-10','2008-01-28','2012-01-18')), lwd = 1:3,
       lty = c('dotted','dashed','solid'), col = c('red','blue','green'))
## add company labels
text(x = date, y = cost, pos = 3, xpd = NA,
     labels = ifelse(cost <= 3000, company, ''))
title(ylab = 'Cost', line = 5)
box('plot', bty = 'l')
```

[image]

To address some specific questions:

1. I use `as.Date`. R stores dates similarly to stata

   ```
   abline(v = as.Date(c('2007-09-10','2008-01-28','2012-01-18')), lwd = 1:3,
          lty = c('dotted','dashed','solid'), col = c('red','blue','green'))
   ```
2. use formatting

   ```
   format(pretty(cost), scientific = FALSE, big.mark = ',')
   # [1] "      0" " 20,000" " 40,000" " 60,000" " 80,000" "100,000"
   ```
3. you can of course create some subsets if you are more comfortable with that, but there is usually a way to do a one-liner in r

   ```
   ifelse(cost <= 3000, company, '')
   # [1] "ACo"  ""     "CInd" ""
   ```

Most of the base plot functions are vectorized which is why this is so easy. And I am not a ggplot wizard, and it usually results in a headache for me when I try to do very specifically formatted plots like these. Generally, ggplot is good for nice, quick, dirty graphs. If you want something very specific or to publish, base r graphics is the way to go.

Comment: Right arm for the plug for base graphics. I have the same difficulty. The addition of data-driven annotation to ggplot objects remains a puzzle for me.  Plus, I cannot get into the code the way I can with base or lattice graphics. I can't tell you the number of times I have encountered a link to the `ggplot2::layer` function only to find .... basically empty space when I follow the link. I've just checked, again. There's no there there.

Comment: If your graph is in line with Hadley's philosophical viewpoints you can produce high quality graphs for publication quite easily (and usually with less code than needed for base graphics). It's only when you want to do something not supported by ggplot2 that you run into trouble and are better of with base. Nowadays, I usually use base graphs for quick and dirty and ggplot2 for publication (as long as I don't need a secondary axis).

Comment: This is great. Thanks! Just a head's up to other people trying to apply this code to their data, for the text() section near the bottom, I found that (1) I had to call both the data frame and the vector (dataframe$vector) otherwise I got an error saying it couldn't find the object, and (2) I had to specify that the "company" variable be read as a character (even though it's a factor) or it would display a number instead. So that section, I tweaked to 
> text(x = thedata$date, y = thedata$cost, pos = 3, xpd = NA,
     labels = ifelse(thedata$cost <= 3000, as.character(hang$coo), ''))

Comment: @rawr Just a quick follow-up question: how do I override the date range displayed on the x-axis to display the full date range instead of a company's specific date range? For example, if I am interested in, say, a 5-year period (2008-2013) but a company had zero transactions in 2008 and -09, as is, the code above will only display 2010-2013 for that specific company. Is there a way to force it to display 2008-2013 to show that the company is a newcomer in the industry? I tried playing around with xlim() but couldn't get it to work with the code you wrote. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `xlim = as.Date(c('2005','2013'), format = '%Y')` or `xlim = range(date) - c(365 * 5, 0)` with the code above

Answer (score 3):

So here is a `ggplot` method which, I think, produces what you are asking.

```
library(ggplot2)
key.events <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("2007-09-10","2008-01-28","2012-01-18")))
ggplot(thedata[thedata$cost>3000,],aes(x=date,y=cost))+ 
  geom_point(shape=1,size=3)+
  geom_text(aes(label=company),vjust=-1)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.2,0.2))+
  geom_vline(data=key.events, size=1,
             aes(xintercept=as.integer(date),color=factor(date),linetype=factor(date)))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","green"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dotted","dashed","solid"))+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! I just ran into two issues when trying to apply it to my full dataset: (1) the y-value tick mark labels are still in scientific notation (e.g. 8e+05 instead of 800,000), and (2) the x-axis does not match up with 0, so there is a big gap of white space between where the plotted observations start appearing at 0 and above, and the x-axis line. Do you know why that would be?